# Какие действия выполняет данный скрипт?

Tags: linux, bash

Скажите, пожалуйста, что выполняет данный скрипт? какие действия?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {2000..2017}; do
    for j in {00..12}; do
        mv $i$j*jpg $i/$j
    done
done
```

Непонятен знак "/"
и mv это перенос в другой каталог или переименование?

Comment: Разобрали картинки каждый год в свою папку.  `/` - это как \ в винде.  `mv` - это и перенос, и переименование

Comment: ESkri, а можете поподробнее, пожалуйста объяснить. 
У меня выводит при выполнении данного скрипта с помощью  bash <имя файла.sh> такое значение:

mv:  cannot stat '200001*jpg' : No such file or directory

Что означает звёздочка перед jpg?      

Разбирает картинки и переносит в какую папку?  
там вроде и файлы i и j и непонятный $i/$j.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Понимаю, вероятно, вопрос для школьника слабенького :(

Comment: У вас первый цикл - перебор лет с 2000 по 2017, внутри - перебор по месяцам, внутри второго цикла - перемещение всех картинок вида годмесяц.jpg в соответствующие директории год/месяц. Вместо * логично было бы увидеть точку, может опечатка?

Comment: `mv: cannot stat '200001*jpg'` - это значит что mv не нашла файлов по этой маске.  Ну нет так нет, всё ок.

Comment: `{00..12}` - у вас что, 13 месяцев в году ?) для отладки скрипта можете добавить в его начало строку `set -x`